# Difference between content-addressable memory and associative memory?

Tags: memory, theoretical-neuroscience, nef, spa

Often when I'm reading theoretical neuroscience publications, such as "[Towards an integration of deep learning and neuroscience](http://biorxiv.org/content/early/2016/06/13/058545)", as well as "[Memory and the Computational Brain](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1405122870.html)", theorists often mention the importance of content-addressable memories. They are defined as follows in the former publication:

> Content addressable memories are classic models in neuroscience. Most simply, they allow us to recognize a situation
>   similar to one that we have seen before, and to “fill in” stored
>   patterns based on partial or noisy information, but they may also be
>   put to use as sub-components of many other functions.

Is the Associative Memory often used in SPA-based models, such as the model used in "[Biologically Plausible, Human-Scale Knowledge Representation](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/cogs.12261/abstract;jsessionid=B9F9C1072A3265CBBFBF6879D268AD33.f02t03)", the same thing as a content-addressable memories?

Comment: Might be relevant: http://suns.mit.edu/articles/Bar_TICS2007.pdf

Comment: That would be an example of a content addressable memory. But there are other kinds, like Hopfield nets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory):

> Content-addressable memory (CAM) is a special type of computer memory
>   used in certain very-high-speed searching applications. It is also
>   known as associative memory, associative storage, or associative array [...]
>   It compares input search data (tag) against a table of stored data,
>   and returns the address of matching data (or in the case of
>   associative memory, the matching data)

As noted in the above question, there are many implementations of content-addressable memories in neural networks, such as the Hamming network and Hopfield networks. The Associative Memory used in SPA-based models performs the same function as these aforementioned networks and the Wikipedia description. Given a SPA vector as input, the Associative Memory outputs the corresponding vector as an output. Thus, the SPA-based Associative Memory is a content-addressable memory.