# What's the difference between a Hamming and Hopfield network?

Tags: theoretical-neuroscience, computational-modeling

I have recently discovered that [both Hamming and Hopfield networks are both content addressable memories](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/15741/4397). However, what is the difference between these two networks designs and their performance?

Comment: www.dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc?AD=ADA182255 - Hamming networks require fewer connections and often outperform Hopfield nets.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn yep, that's the paper I was using to craft my own answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopfield and Hamming networks are older connectionist networks used to classify noisy binary input data.

Hopfield networks are the basis for Hamming networks, so let's focus on those first.

A Hopfield network is a set of neurons that do classification via mutual inhibition, as shown in the figure below from Wikipedia:

[image: mutual-inhibition]

Note the neurons are not like your typical biologically plausible neurons, they have two states "+1" and "-1". Their update rule, which forces them into an output pattern, enables these two states.

A Hamming network is a two-layer network, as shown in this figure (taken from [here](http://home.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/hamming_en/)) where the data is flowing from the bottom:

[image: hamming-net]

As you can see, the second layer, sometimes called the MaxNet layer, is identical to the Hopfield Network, however the input layer resembles a classic single-layer perceptron. This single-layer perceptron is train according to the [Hamming Distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) of the inputs.

Performance wise, as shown in the conclusion "[A Comparison of Hamming and Hopfield
Neural Nets for Pattern Classification](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjxyqCW_M7OAhWGJR4KHcHXBq8QFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dtic.mil%2Fcgi-bin%2FGetTRDoc%3FAD%3DADA182255&usg=AFQjCNGoj9tbl99gQ61YpCzOl_gP4k-clQ&sig2=AKhP5wek8y-0K6Tgg6ltvg)" by Lippmann et al., Hamming nets generally out-perform Hopfield nets.